# dateFromString day month year in plain text

Tags: objective-c

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateInitial = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.labelDateInitial.text];
NSDate *dateEnd = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.labelDateEnd.text];
NSLog(@"%@", dateInitial);
NSLog(@"%@", dateEnd);
```

Why i receive null value for both dateInitial and dateEnd ?

in label date is in plain text

nine november 2012

is it correct dd-MM-yyyy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date string value is `nine november 2012` then using `dd-MM-yyyy` will not help as its expecting date string as `09-11-2012`.

For month as `november`,  I think you can use `MMMMM`, not sure about `nine`.

i.e. if `09 November 2012` then `dd MMMM yyyy` can be used.

**Edit:**

To get the date formatted in specific timezone, set the timezone to the format as below:

```
   [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

Use appropriated Timezone string e.g. `EST`, `PTC` etc.

Comment: and for day ? dd should be ok ? one more: NSLog is correct ? Or %@ is not good for passing NSDate value ?

Comment: @Fabrizio `%@` should be fine. I am not sure about the day. I have never seen text in the date place. I have seen the day e.g. Monday or Mon. One idea could be manipulate your string to convert nine into 09.

Comment: I'm trying [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d MMMMM YYYY"]; in my label text i've 09 (not nine)

Comment: @Fabrizio I think it should be two `d`s i.e. `dd`. Is that not working with `09`?

Comment: It's odd. For the string 09 november 2012 i have in the console NSLog 2012-12-28 23:00:00 +0000 any hints ? Thanks

Comment: @Fabrizio: I looks better than the null. Only otherthing I doubt is the case i.e. `November` in place of `novemeber`.

Comment: my bad: in the label there's november and not November, it's very odd i receive that results (even if they are better than null, i agree :) )

Comment: @Fabrizio: Did you try correcting the month as `November`? Also would you mind logging `self.labelDateInitial.text` and see it really the right date string?

Comment: i see the issue now. If i have 01 november 2012 i have an NSLog 31 october 2012, probably i need to adjust the DateFormat to NSLocale, [dateFormat setLocale: ]; what need to insert after setLocale: ?

Comment: @Fabrizio NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIdentifier];
    [dateFormat setLocale:locale];

Comment: @Fabrizio: Try setting the timezone instead of Locale as : `[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];`. Mention appropriate timezone in the statement.

Comment: @Fabrizio: Finally, it worked for you. I am happy!! It becomes little difficult to help by knowing little fragment of the code and context only.